# Dependency injection on base class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Would it work to setup DI for a class B that has inheritance from class A, which in turns implemets interface I, like this:

```
public interface I {
 SomeMethod();
}

public abstract class A : I {
//some code ...
}

public class B : A {
//some code...
}
```

Question is would DI work on such a scheme, I mean setting DI for the B class?

Comment: Yes why shouldn't it?

Comment: I just thought that DI would only work, let's say, for class A, which is the one that implements the interface

Comment: B implements the interface as well because it is derived from A (at least in the languages i know, assuming the above is c#)
When the DI framework resolves it, you get an instance that implements I, so any additional methods and properties on B are 'hidden'

Comment: Yes, that's what I supposed to happen, but I'm having trouble setting up DI in a config like that, and I thought that not directly implementing the interface would be the cause

Comment: I think you should make your question more concrete. It is currently really abstract and I would even say _unclear what you're asking_. What does it mean to "to setup DI for a class B"? Can you give a realistic example with classes and dependencies? Where does Dependency Injection come into play here? Neither class `A` nor class `B` have any dependencies being _injected_? How are class `A` and `B` expected to be used/injected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually DI containers (such as Castle, Unity, Autofac etc.) let you differ the type registration and the interface linking.

F.e. in Autofac you can register single type and declare a few base classes and interfaces:

```
builder.RegisterType<B>()
       .AsSelf()
       .As<A>()
       .As<I>();
```

Now the instance of `B` class will be resolved when you need `B` class, `A` class, or `I` interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Core you can simply use a generic Base Controller class:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller
{
    private IFoo _fooInstance;
    private IBar _barInstance;

    protected IFoo _foo => _fooInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IFoo>();
    protected IBar _bar => _barInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IBar>();
}
```

and if you are using Razor pages:

```
class BasePageModel<T> : PageModel where T : class
{
    private IFoo _fooInstance;
    private IBar _barInstance;

    protected IFoo _foo => _fooInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IFoo>();
    protected IBar _bar => _barInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IBar>();
}
```